# error in RAC clustering part in oracle 11 g on redhat 5

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, redhat

i have this error while configuring the rac node
You must enter unique values for the public node name, the private node name and the virtual hostname for all nodes in the cluster. The name, YOUR-HOSTNAME , that you entered is being used by more than once for the same node.
what is the origin of the problem i have configured three adresses public private and virtual
you found below the file /etc/hosts with the different adresses so how can i solve the problem ?*

## public

10.128.0.0 rac1
10.128.0.1 rac2

## private

192.168.10.2 rac1-priv
192.168.10.3 rac2-priv

## virtual

10.128.0.2 rac1-vip
10.128.0.3 rac2-vip

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign network address which is reserved for IP standard!
X.X.X.0 indicate network address!

Please choose another IP. You can select the IP address +1 or +2.

This example will dispel your doubts:

**public**
10.128.0.2 rac1 10.128.0.3 rac2


**private**
192.168.10.2 rac1-priv 192.168.10.3 rac2-priv


**virtual**
10.128.0.4 rac1-vip 10.128.0.5 rac2-vip

Please correct your IP's and /etc/hosts on all of your cluster nodes.